# json iterate and put details into drop down and select box

Tags: jquery, json

i've a json as shown below...in that bank details should be put into a select box and employee details should be put into a table......but don't know how to get bank and employee details seperately and iterate each to put into required sections (select & table)

can anyone please tell me how to do this

```
{ "bank": [
             { "branch": "KLM" },
             { "manager": "manu" }
          ], 
  "employee": [
             { "id": "IDE123" },
             { "name": "ronny" }
          ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery.each in order to iterate your JSON result such as below:

```
$(jsonResult).each(function(index, element) {
   //for bank records
   $(element.bank).each(function(i, bank) {
        console.log(bank.branch);
        console.log(bank.manager);
   });

   //for employee records
   $(element.employee).each(function(i, employee) {
        console.log(employee.id);
        console.log(employee.name);
   });

});
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: sir if the bank details will be like "bank": [{ "1": "manu" , "2": "sita","3": "raju" , "4": "felmy" }].........then what will we do

Comment: you mean to say details would be a collection or array, isn't it?

Comment: @user2040500, actually in my answer i am doing the same.

Comment: can we interate like for(var key in element.bank) {
            html += "<option value=" + key  + ">" +element.bank[key] + "</option>"
        }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the json in a `data` variable, you can access the bank details as `data.bank` and the employee details as `data.employee`. Then for each one, you have an array of objects, so iterate over it as such:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.bank.length; i++) { // Iterate over each object in the array
  for (var key in data.bank[i]) { // Iterate over the key in the object
    if (data.bank[i].hasOwnPropety(key)) {
      console.log(key); // "branch"
      console.log(data.bank[i][key]); // "KLM"
    }
  }
}
```